# Debugging PHP on NetBeans 6.8 without Apache

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, netbeans6.8

Is it possible to debug PHP projects on Glashfish with NetBeans 6.8 without installing Apache server?
After I press CTRL+F5 im getting 404 not found error.

As ASP.NET developer I have (I think) similiar developer server bundled with Visual Studio, so there is no need to install any other server like IIS. Am I right that Glassfish is similiar developer server, so why Im getting 404?

Thanks
Darek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Netbeans page.

To successfully debug PHP applications in the NetBeans IDE for PHP, you need to have the PHP engine, the Apache local web server, and the XDebug debugger installed and configured for PHP development. If you have difficulties getting XDebug to work, see the NetBeans wiki on XDebug and/or ask the community at users@php.netbeans.org.

I hope it helps